# Android - trying to get data back from Activity 2 to Activity 1 and from method to method

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

First of all - I've already checked different tutorials, but wasn't able to complete my task :(

I'm calling Activity 2 from *onAddEventClicked* method in Activity 1 to open the layout and let the user type the name in EditText. Then I want to close Activity 2, send captured name back to Activity 1 and use it to set the name parameter when creating new **event** in ArrayList: *event.setName(dataFromActivity2)*.

I'm able to save EditText's data to String **dataFromActivity2**, but how should I pass it from *onAddEventClicked* method back to *onAddEventClicked* method and set event.setName(dataFromActivity2) ?

Unfortunately I've tried so many times with no luck. Could you guide me with any hints / tips please? I know that the solution is probably simple, but I'm still a beginner... :( Should I use SharedPreferences insted of *startActivityForResult*?

ACTIVITY1 :

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WeekView.EventClickListener, MonthLoader.MonthChangeListener, WeekView.EventLongPressListener, WeekView.EmptyViewLongPressListener, WeekView.EmptyViewClickListener, WeekView.AddEventClickListener {
private static final int TYPE_DAY_VIEW = 1;
private static final int TYPE_THREE_DAY_VIEW = 2;
private static final int TYPE_WEEK_VIEW = 3;
private int mWeekViewType = TYPE_THREE_DAY_VIEW;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
String TAG = "***";
private WeekView mWeekView;
private ArrayList<WeekViewEvent> mNewEvents;
...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        String dataFromActivity2= data.getStringExtra("fav");
}


@Override
public void onAddEventClicked(Calendar startTime, Calendar endTime) {

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Test2.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

WeekViewEvent event = new WeekViewEvent();
event.setId(7);
event.setName(fav);
event.setStartTime(startTime);
event.setEndTime(endTime);
event.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.event_color_03));

Log.d(TAG, "Intent test:" +fav);
mNewEvents.add(event);
mWeekView.notifyDatasetChanged();
}

...
}
```

ACTIVITY 2:

```
public class Test2 extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_test);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etv_test);
            String favourities=et.getText().toString();

            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("fav", favourities);

            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();//finishing activity
            Toast.makeText(Test2.this, "INTENT CONTAINS:" + intent.getExtras(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }});}}
```

Comment: forgot to mention, that I cannot change: @Override
public void onAddEventClicked(Calendar startTime, Calendar endTime) to take in another String parameter, as I'm getiing errors "Method does not overrid method from its superclass" .. Can anyone help a newbie, please?

Comment: Try putting the part where you add the new event into the OnActivityResult method instead of onAddEventClicked

Comment: @cvanbeek - thanks for your response! I can't move that part, as creating new event requires overriding onAddEventClicked. And that method takes is two parameters to set start and end time. Any other ideas ? :)

Comment: @cvanbeek thans for your tip - was worth trying! job done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your code for event creation into the onActivityResult method:

```
   private Calendar startTime, endTime;
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            String dataFromActivity2 = data.getStringExtra("fav");
            // create event here
            WeekViewEvent event = new WeekViewEvent();
            event.setId(7);
            event.setName(dataFromActivity2);
            event.setStartTime(startTime);
            event.setEndTime(endTime);
            event.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.event_color_03));

            Log.d(TAG, "Intent test:" + dataFromActivity2);
            mNewEvents.add(event);
            mWeekView.notifyDatasetChanged();
    }
```

In onAddEventClicked you have to save its parameters (startTime, endTime) to instance variables - to be able to use them in onActivityResult:

```
    @Override
    public void onAddEventClicked(Calendar startTime, Calendar endTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Test2.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your response :) I've just tried that, but the event's name is still blank. Maybe there's something wrong with the code order? I've spent 3 hours trying to make it work..with no luck

Comment: @Matt ah, I just noticed that you have another problem in the code - when you’re creating the event that name variable is not set yet, see the edited answer.

Comment: its' working, but there's something weird going on. When I'm adding 1st event and let's say putting  "abc" into EditText - the name remains blank. Now, when I'm creating 2nd event and type in different data, the name is finally visible but takes in 1st event's name...

No I will try to find a way and move the code for event creation into onActivityResult method as reccomended by you guys :) We will se what happens then

Comment: A BIG THANK YOU my friend for providing me working solutions - well done! :)

Comment: By the way - let me know your adreess details so I can send you a beer keg - one of Polish finests :)